# Problem on CPU scheduling algorithms in OS

Tags: linux, operating-system, cpu, scheduling

Five batch jobs A, B, C, D and E arrive at a computer centre at almost at the same time. They have estimated running times of 10,6,2,4 and 8 minutes. Their priorities are 3,5,2,1 and 4 respectively, with 5 being the highest priority. For each of the following scheduling algorithm determine the turnaround time of each process and waiting time of each process. Ignore process switching overhead. Mention which algorithm results in minimal average waiting time. 1. Round Robin 2. Priority scheduling 3. First come first served 4. Shortest job first. For case i) assume that system is multiprocessing and each job gets its fair share of the CPU. (time quantum 2 minutes0. For cases (ii),(iii) and (iv) assume that only one job runs at a time, until it finishes. All jobs are completely CPU bound.

proper answer with partition required